# One sentence in one line

Tags: fonts

I want to make the first sentence/citation fit into one line. I already tried it with `\small` and `\microtype`. But nothing seems to work.

[image]

These are my commands:

```
\HRule\\[1.4cm]
\MSdoublespacing
{ \huge\bfseries Article review}\\[0.4cm]
{Alvi, E. \& Senbeta, A. (2012): Does foreign aid reduce poverty?. Journal of International Development} \\[0.3cm]
{Easterly, W. (2003). Can foreign aid buy growth?. Journal of Economic Perspectives}\\[0.3cm] 
\HRule \\[2.4cm]
\MSonehalfspacing
```

Comment: Please extend you code to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Ideally your code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and should allow us to reproduce the problem without the need of changing anything. This would also help us to test our ideas. Currently we would have to guess how several of the shown commands are defined and how wide the text area is. This makes it difficult to find a good solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Without knowledge of which font is in use, what the applicable font size may be, and how wide the textblock is, there's simply not enough meaningful information to go by to diagnose the situation and propose a cure. Also, how or where are `\MSdoublespacing`, `\MSonehalfspacing`, and `\HRule` defined?

Comment: Using `\looseness=-1` just at the start of the line of text might help. Or not.

Comment: Yhre is also \footnotesize, \scriptsize and \tiny, plus adjustbox.